# How to get all related objects from a reverse foreign key Django serializer (one-to-many)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, one-to-many, django-serializer

I have been trying to create a Trello-like clone and storing my 'Lists' and 'Applications' as separate models with a foreign key on my 'Applications' model to create a One-To-Many between Lists and Applications. I usually use Node and Sequelize and have been unsuccessful in trying to query my Lists and also returning all the Applications with the List's ID as the Applications foreign key. I suspect I am just missing something silly on my Serializers.

I've tried a few things that broke the code, but now I just have it returning the List's fields like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "My First List"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "My Second List"
    }, 
]
```

when in reality what I really want back is something like:

```
[
    {       "id": 1,
            "title": "My First List",
                "applications": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "company_name": "Spotify",
                            "position": "Web Engineer",
                            "date_applied": "2019-09-09",
                            "application_id": "xv112_cv",
                            "priority_level": "High",
                            "company_contact_email": "jg@spotify.com",
                            "notes": "Seems promising",
                            "location": "New York",
                            "status_list": "1"
                    },
                    {
                            "id": "2",
                            "company_name": "Foursquare",
                            "position": "Client Solutions Engineer",
                            "date_applied": "2019-10-09",
                            "application_id": "fsq_app_1",
                            "priority_level": "High",
                            "company_contact_email": "jdwyer@foursquare.com",
                            "notes": "Interview on 9/29/19",
                            "location": "New York",
                            "status_list": "1"
                    },
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "id": "2"
                "title": "My Second List",
                "applications": "applications": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "company_name": "Etsy",
                        "position": "Web Engineer",
                        "date_applied": "2019-09-09",
                        "application_id": "12345",
                        "priority_level": "High",
                        "company_contact_email": "",
                        "notes": "Seems promising",
                        "location": "New York",
                        "status_list": 2
                }
            ] 
        }
]
```

Here are my models:

```
class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Application(models.Model):
    _list = models.ForeignKey(
        List, related_name='list', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_applied = models.DateField(
        default=date.today(), blank=True)
    application_id = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    [ . . . ]
```

And my Serializers are here:

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    applications_set = ApplicationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ('title', 'applications_set',)
        depth = 1


class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = '__all__'
```

I know that I don't have an 'applications' or 'applications_set' field on my List model, but I figured it's not necessary due to the fkey association defined.

Is what I am trying to do possible?? What am I missing?

Also for reference are my viewsets:

```
class AllListsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = List.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    serializer_class = ListSerializer

class ApplicationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Application.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = ApplicationSerializer
```

**EDIT:**
Figured it out - on my Application model I just made a small tweak to the related_name attribute:

```
status_list = models.ForeignKey(
        List, related_name='applications', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )
```

and on my ListSerializer:

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    applications = ApplicationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ('title', 'applications',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given your FK a related_name. That overrides `application_set`. You've called it `list`, which is not at all a good name, but since you've set it that is what you need to use as the field name in the serializer.

I would recommend removing that `related_name` attribute - and also renaming the FK itself, you shouldn't have an underscore prefix in a field name.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I've renamed ```list``` to ```status_list``` in the Applications model and removed the related_name attribute as well. I've reflected this in my List serializer but still nothing is returned but the List info without the applications nested in after running the migration. Any other suggestions?
**Also don't know if this matters or not but the List and Application models, serializers and viewsets are all in their own app in the project, not in the same app. Thanks